# F# using with indent syntax

Tags: f#

there is

```
using (new SqlConnection(insql)) ( Open(); )
```

or

```
using (new SqlConnection(insql)) <| fun c ->
   c.Open()
```

I want indent but without c alike

```
using (new SqlConnection(insql)) ->
   Open()
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do that; since `Open` is an instance method it needs to be preceded by the object which it's being called on.

I'd typically avoid `using` entirely and use a `use`-binding:

```
use c = new SqlConnection(insql)
c.Open()
```